# Minimum number of steps for a knight on chess board (5 x 5 or under)

Tags: combinatorics, chessboard

Given two squares on a chess board of 5x5 or **under**, how can we determine the minimum number of moves required by a knight to reach one square starting from the other, including a way to determine if it is impossible to reach the knight?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: This is a fairly well-researched question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour

Answer (score 3):

Model your knight's errand as a graph: the squares are vertices, edges connect squares if a knight can jump from one to the other. Finding the shortest sequence from one to the other can then be done using e.g. [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).